# Concerning Pros and Cons

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I have two questions:

1. When considering gains and losses, advantages and disadvantages, pros and cons, etc., what is a good word for the traits which are equal between the two options. "Equalities", "draws", "ties", etc. all seem a little out of place (especially stylistically and word-length-wise). Moreover, "draw" feels too similar to "drawback".
2. What is the opposite of "benefit" (which matches stylistically)? "Disadvantage" does not work because that opposes "advantage", "con" does not work because that opposes "pro", etc. "Drawback" is as good as I can presently get, but I am not satisfied with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the rationale for rejecting the words you considered. For example, what's wrong with *con* opposing *pro*?

Comment: You should post this as two questions.

Comment: Lawrence: "Con" is fine for "pro", but I just consider those to be too closely related, as a pair, for "con" to be used with anything else. I would not say "benefits and cons". The only word that can go with "con" is "pro".

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you are looking for one of 'equivalent', 'moderate', 'common', 
   'indifferent' or 'identical'.
2. Words like 'downside' and 'flaw' can be a good option for you (stylistically). Other words like 'pitfall' and 'drawback' can also be used. 'Drawback' is used a lot with 'benefit'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean “neutral” options. They negate or neutralize each other.

The opposite of “benefit” could be “harm” depending on the subject being discussed.

Comment: 'Cost' would work better than 'harm' for some subjects.